# Getting "SSL handshake failed" when creating Kafka Producer and Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm creating a consumer and a producer in Java, but I'm getting the "SSL handshake failed" when I attempt to produce a record/consume a topic.

All of my research is telling me I'm missing certificates.  But here's the thing.  We're connecting via API key, so in theory I shouldn't NEED any certificates or JKS files.  I know I didn't need to specify any when I got Conduktor up and running.  I'm using that to produce to and consume from topics without issue.

Going back to my platform team, they just keep telling me to confirm my API key credentials are correct. They are.  When I ask them for the JKS files I need, they have no idea what I'm talking about.  So, I'm kind of stuck.

Any suggestions?

I tried just specifying the `sasl.jaas.config` property, which everyone keeps assuring me should be all I need.  I've confirmed and reconfirmed I've specified it properly.

Comment: BTW, the cluster admins need their own JKS/PEM files to setup authentication on the brokers, so they _should_ know what you're asking for... What do you mean "via API Key"? Do you have some custom authorization? `sasl.jaas.config` is not the same as  SSL/TLS settings... Also, make sure you are connected to the correct port for the bootstrap servers setting since you could have both `PLAINTEXT` (that maybe Conduktor is using?) and `SSL` port addresses that you've set and are throwing errors?